# Isomorphisms of rings and their generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It's been a while since I touched abstract algebra, so please correct me if I'm wrong here: if I wanted to construct an isomorphism between the polynomial rings with integer coefficients $\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_2]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_1^{-1}+1]$, I would identify $x_1$ with $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x_1^{-1}+1$; would the explicit isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_2]\to \mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_1^{-1}+1]$ be simply to take the generator $\varphi(x_1+x_2)=x_1+x_1^{-1}+1$?

Also, please bear with me a bit, but if I wanted an explicit isomorphism
$\mathbb{Z}[x_1+ x_1^{-1}+x_2+x_2^{-1}+1,2+x_1x_2+x_1x_2^{-1}+x_1+x_1^{-1}x_2+x_1^{-1}x_2^{-1}+x_1^{-1}+x_2+x_2^{-1}]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_1^{-1}+x_2+x_2^{-1},1+x_1x_2+x_1x_2^{-1}+x_1^{-1}x_2+x_1^{-1}x_2^{-1}]$,
would I just send the generators to each other, e.g. $x_1+ x_1^{-1}+x_2+x_2^{-1}+1\mapsto x_1+x_1^{-1}+x_2+x_2^{-1}$ and $2+x_1x_2+x_1x_2^{-1}+x_1+x_1^{-1}x_2+x_1^{-1}x_2^{-1}+x_1^{-1}+x_2+x_2^{-1}\mapsto $
$1+x_1x_2+x_1x_2^{-1}+x_1^{-1}x_2+x_1^{-1}x_2^{-1}$?

Is there perhaps another way to realize this isomorphism?

Comment: One problem with $\phi(x_1)=x_1$ is that $x_1$ isn't in ${\bf Z}[x_1+x_2]$.

Comment: I meant $\varphi(x_1)=x_1$ when restricted to $x_1$, so we identify $x_1$ with $x_1$; for example $\varphi(x_1+x_2)=x_1+x_1^{-1}+1$. I think this gives an isomorphism of rings...

Comment: What does "when restricted to $x_1$" mean? You would have to *extend* $\phi$ in order for $\phi(x_1)$ to make sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right; sorry for the wrong terminology. I simply meant that the isomorphism $\varphi$ takes $x_1+x_2$ to $x_1+x_1^{-1}+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have more luck here if you're explicit about what these rings are.  For instance, what is $\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_2]$?  Polynomial rings have very concrete definitions.  So you should try to realize all of your rings as subquotients (i.e. quotients of subrings) of polynomial rings.  For instance, $\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_2]$ is the subring of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]$ generated by $x_1+x_2$.  Similarly, $\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_1^{-1}+1]$ is the subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_1^{-1}]$ generated by $x_1+x_1^{-1}+1$.  One can define $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_1^{-1}]$ to be the quotient of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,y_1]$ by the ideal generated by $x_1y_1-1$ (so that the image of $y_1$ in the quotient corresponds to $x_1^{-1}$).

Once you've defined your rings precisely, you can then use the fact that one can define a map from a polynomial ring (over $\mathbb{Z}$) to **any** commutative ring by mapping the indeterminates to any elements you like (this is a very nice property of polynomial rings).  To define a map from a quotient of a polynomial ring to another commutative ring, you can map the indeterminates to any elements you like, **provided** that the ideal you've quotiented out by is mapped to zero.

To apply this concretely to your first question, there is a map from $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_1^{-1}]$ that sends $x_1$ to $x_1$ and $x_2$ to $x_1^{-1}$.  Restricting this map to the subring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_2] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]$ yields a map $\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_2] \to \mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_1^{-1}]$.  Since the image of this map lies in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1 + x_1^{-1}+1]$ (which, incidentally, is equal to $\mathbb{Z}[x_1+x_1^{-1}]$), you can restrict the codomain to get the map you want.  This gives exactly that map you said: it maps $x_1+x_2$ to $x_1 +x_1^{-1} + 1$, but it justifies why such a map exists.

Now try the same thing with your second map.  This will be little bit more involved, but the idea is the same.